# Need help understanding a Cache concept

Tags: caching, operating-system, disk

I've been reading a lot about operating systems and all lately. I understand how cache works and what is it used for.
However, when I asked a question to myself, I was unable to find an answer.

> If a cache can be made as large as the device it is caching (for instance, a cache as large as a disk), why not do so and eliminate the device.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the cache is in-memory, it's not persistent, meaning you'll lose it once your machine is reboot. If nothing else, you'll need persistent storage (disk) to avoid losing data on restarts and power loses.

Answer (score 1):

For a disk cache, there's no technical limit why a battery-backed RAM cache or flash storage usually used for HDD cache can't be combined together to provide terabytes of capacity. Your average user won't be using those RAM-based storage products because it's far more expensive than normal storage and they still consume too much power to leave unplugged for hours. We *are* leaving SSHD behind for full flash storage, but even they have RAM cache to reduce & consolidate IO calls.

For CPU cache, there's actually a practical limit to it, they're taking precious physical space that can be used for other unit, increasing distance (thus latency), and generate heat (which put a hard limit no matter how large is your cooling budget). That's why CPU cache is multilevel instead, with the small L1 tightly coupled to a core, the bigger L2 shared by multiple cores, and the slower but even bigger L3 with the slower but cheaper component. Even with an unlimited budget and an exotic process, a multilevel cache CPU will have better performance than a single-level cache CPU that's forced to put everything on (relatively) far silicon and suffering from the latency.